# How to get the image from image picker and display into a add form?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, imagepicker

I have the struct below to handle the image picker but I'm unable to pass the image selected to the view to be displayed. Selected path below prints correctly location of the file but how assign this selected file to the pic into the view ?

```
    struct FileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Select File") {
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png","jpg","jpeg"]
            openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
                if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                    let selectedPath = openPanel.url!.path
                    print(selectedPath)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below the place where I display the selected image:

```
struct NewPost: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var postToEdit: Item?
    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    ...
    @State var fileUrl: URL?
    
    var header: String {
        postToEdit == nil ? "Create Post" : "Edit Post"
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {

    ...Form Code

    // Displaying Image if its selected...
                
Section(header: Text("Picture").foregroundColor(Color("blue")).font(.title2)) {
                        
if let fileUrl = fileUrl, let img = NSImage(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
                            
    Image(nsImage: img)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1))
        .opacity(1)
        .frame(minWidth: 120, maxWidth: 120, minHeight: 120, maxHeight: 120)
                            
     }
                        
 if pic.count != 0 {
                            
          Image(nsImage: NSImage(data: pic)!)
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFill()
              .clipShape(Circle())
              .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1))
              .opacity(1)
              .frame(minWidth: 120, maxWidth: 120, minHeight: 120, maxHeight: 120)
         }
     }
     .cornerRadius(10)
```

Updated code above based on response below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Binding` to pass data from a child view back up to a parent:

```
struct FileView: View {
    @Binding var fileUrl : URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Select File") {
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png","jpg","jpeg"]
            openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
                if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                    fileUrl = openPanel.url
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fileUrl: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FileView(fileUrl: $fileUrl)
            if let fileUrl = fileUrl, let image =  NSImage(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
                Image(nsImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that in the child, it's `@Binding`, but in the parent, it's `@State`.

**Updated version, using `Data`**:

```
struct FileView: View {
    @Binding var fileData : Data?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Select File") {
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png","jpg","jpeg"]
            openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
                if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                    guard let url = openPanel.url, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                        //handle errors here
                        return
                    }
                    fileData = data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fileData: Data?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FileView(fileData: $fileData)
            if let fileData = fileData, let image =  NSImage(data: fileData) {
                Image(nsImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: obviously, not doing any error handling for not being able to read from the URL or anything in this example*

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much but I still have just one issue on that. This form is a .sheet that receives data when editing, not new, coming from List view and image is saved as Data into CoreData which was previously assigned as the code above. Now when editing how can I display the image ? I'm updating the code above with the current properties I have.

Comment: It is not clear to me from your update what you're trying to do. Do you just need me to update my answer to use `Data` instead of a `URL`?

Comment: I just would like your help to understand the best way to handle in case of editing a post because with your help I could implement a new post. When editing the post, the image from core data is not displayed and I don't know how to handle it the way you solved here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just still not sure what that means, exactly, so I'm just guessing. How about you send the `Data` from the original image as a parameter (non-Binding) and show it unless there is data in the `fileUrl` Binding?

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. I followed your suggestion as you can see on the edited code above but now I don't know how to save one or another depending if creating a new post (using fileURL image) or editing a post (NSImage: (data: pic) coming from core data). :(

Comment: Sorry, but there's just not enough code there to figure out what you're trying to do. I don't see anything about "saving" anything. You're still referring to `pic`, which seems to be data that you're getting from...somewhere? Maybe the CoreData object?  Again, I can rewrite my answer using `Data` if that'll help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229956/discussion-between-eddief-and-jnpdx).